# Storing input file into multiple data types

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm stuck on how to get a name stored in a string including white space characters, and then get the rest of the input stored separately as an int, char, and double. In other words, four separate data types: string, int, char, double.

Here is the file contents I need to read and extract data from line by line. I need the name extraction to work for all types of names.

Also, the following file contents are in this order, respectively:

String: Name
Int: Account Number
Char: Account Type
Double: Usage Amount

John H. Doe 1001    H   5693.3

James Randolph, Jr. 3333    H   1000.0

Sara Lawrence-Smith 2456    H   3999999.5

Good Time Industries    4678    C   10000000.1

Big Business, Inc.  6757    I   12500849.9

Mom and Pop Shop    5002    C   4000000.7

The O'Leary Company 8022    I   9999999.9

Here is my little bit of code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void readBillingRecord(ifstream& fin, string& name, int& accNum, char& type, double& usage);

int main()
{
string billingDataFile = "Water Bill Records.txt";
string billingReportFile = "Water Bill Report.txt";
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
string name;
int accNum;
char type; 
double usage;

fin.open(billingDataFile);
if (fin.fail())
{
cout << "\nError opening " << billingDataFile << " file for reading. \nProgram Terminated. \n";
system("pause");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
readBillingRecord(fin, name, accNum, type, usage);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void readBillingRecord(ifstream& fin, string& name, int& accNum, char& type, double& usage)
{
fin >> name >> accNum >> type >> usage;
cout << name << accNum << type << usage << endl;
}
```

Comment: What sort of volume are you looking at processing, and what do you need to do with the data?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be “that guy” but, this really cries out for

1. Regular expressions (although any method of counting back from the end of the string would do)
2. Not using C++ (sorry, I say this as a big fan of the language)

However, failing that, and presuming that none of the trailing fields is ever missing (or “empty”), your next best bet for extracting those string values is (sadly):

For each line in the file:

1. scan backwards for the separators (spaces), three times, being careful not to go past the start of the line; then use the start of the line and that offset (well, an iterator, hopefully) to construct a new string value
2. extract the remaining three values whatever way you choose

To do this efficiently, you possibly want to look at `mmap()` and `string_view`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to parse the names with the stream functions. Here is a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cnzoLT/2) solution:

```
void readBillingRecord(ifstream& fin, string& name, int& accNum, char& type, double& usage)
{
    std::string line;
    std::regex r{R"(([\D]*) (\d*) (\w) (\d*.?\d*))"};
    std::smatch m;
    while(getline(fin, line)){
        std::regex_match(line, m, r);

        name = m[1];
        accNum = std::stoi(m[2]);
        type = std::string{m[3]}[0];
        usage = std::stod(m[4]);

        std::cout << name << accNum << type << usage << endl;
    }
}
```

With some more error checking:

```
void readBillingRecord(ifstream& fin, string& name, int& accNum, char& type, double& usage)
{
    std::string line;
    std::regex r{R"(([\D]*) (\d*) (\w) (\d*.?\d*))"};
    std::smatch m;
    while(getline(fin, line)){
        static int line_count{-1};
        ++line_count;
        if(!std::regex_match(line, m, r)) {
            std::cout << "No match for line " << line_count << " with text: " << line << '\n';
            continue;
        }
        name = m[1];
        accNum = std::stoi(m[2]);
        type = std::string{m[3]}[0];
        usage = std::stod(m[4]);

        std::cout << name << accNum << type << usage << endl;
    }
}
```

For the following input:

```
John H. Doe 1001 H 5693.3

James Randolph, Jr. 3333 H 1000.0
Sara Law3rence-Smith 2456 H 3999999.5
Good Time Industries 4678 C 10000000.1
Big Business, Inc. 6757 I 12500849.9
Mom and Pop Shop 5002 C 4000000.7
The O'Leary Company 8022 I 9999999.9
```

Produces:

```
John H. Doe 1001H5693.3
No match for line 1 with text:
James Randolph, Jr. 3333H1000
No match for line 3 with text: Sara Law3rence-Smith 2456 H 3999999.5
Good Time Industries 4678C1e+07
Big Business, Inc. 6757I1.25008e+07
Mom and Pop Shop 5002C4e+06
The O'Leary Company 8022I1e+07
```

Comment: Funny, you don't *look* like a ninja ;o)

Comment: I just tried this in the above program and its creating a error (break) at accNum = std::stoi(m[2]). Since this programming is above what I've learned so far, I don't understand the process behind it to solve the issue.

Comment: @HeatherMcIntyre You'll have to use a debugger to see what is going on. I've made an update to show some error checking.